# Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: android, path, java, noclassdeffounderror

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>       java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

[image]

There are two jdk folders in java installation, jdk1.7.0 and jdk1.7.0_10.

[image: jdk folders]

when I navigate to higher one in my case jdk1.7.0_10, java works fine.

[image: Working java]

My path variable is also pointing to jdk1.7.0_10 as shown in below screenshot.
[image: PATH]

It seems everything is fine but still it shows this error.

Comment: Try setting the JAVA_HOME variable to the jdk you want to use. It doesn't seem to find the runtime.

Comment: @Kayaman JAVA_HOME is already set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\

Comment: I think there is a problem in your `ClassPath`. Please check this **[reference](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/)** which has the description of the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows directory was the major culprit, I searched `java.exe` in `C:\Windows` and it was present in Windows directory. It was overshadowing the one in Java’SDK hence causing the problem, deleted it and it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your installation is corrupted.
Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

1. JAVA_HOME should point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10" only. It should not includ 'bin' directory.
2. In your PATH - try moving ".;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin" to first position.

like --- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin; ; ;

1. Try adding '.' in your PATH variable.
   include '.' also in your PATH variable. 
   like PATH - .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;;

@Kayaman JAVA_HOME is already set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\ – Tahir Yasin